# Non-continuous group homomorphism from p-adic field to C*

Tags: rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-groups

Let $F$ be a p-adic field. A character on $F^\times$ is defined as a *continuous* group homomorphism $F^\times\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$. But is there any way to construct a non-continuous group homomorphism $F^\times\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$? Is there even any such homomorphism?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are constructing homomorphisms on the additive group $F$, but the question is about homomorphisms on the multiplicative group $F^\times$, which is not a vector space, so your basis argument does not adapt to $F^\times$.

Comment: It is easy to show that there are $2^c$ homomorphisms (but only $c$ continuous ones). On the other hand there is no way to "construct" an explicit non-continuous one.

Comment: @KConrad Oh, you are right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\mathbf C^\times$ is a divisible group, Zorn’s lemma tells us for every abelian group $G$ and subgroup $H$ that each group homomorphism $H\to \mathbf C^\times$ extends (somehow) to a group homomorphism $G\to\mathbf C^\times$.

Use $G = F^\times$ and $H = \langle u\rangle$, where $u$ is in $\mathcal O_F^\times$ and not a root of unity, so $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z$. Start with the homomorphism $H\to \mathbf C^\times$ where $u^k \to 2^k$ and extend to a homomorphism with domain $F^\times$ by Zorn’s lemma. This homomorphism is not continuous since $\mathcal O_F^\times$ is compact but the homomorphism on this subgroup of $F^\times$ is discontinuous because its image in $\mathbf C^\times$ is unbounded and thus not compact.